# How to assert condition to check if an object is available in json response of an API

Tags: object, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a JSON key value pair which would come for a particular condition satisfies if that condition fails i will not see that key and value how can  assert that using rest API automation code here is the sample snippet.

I have a json key value pair which would come for a particular condition satisfies if that condition fails it will not see that key and value how can i assert that using rest api automation code here is the sample snippet.

"href": "hsgsgs",
"id": "AFSAFAFSASA",
"lastModifiedDate": "2zzzzz0",
"taxExemptFlag": "N",
"channel": "NREG",
** "fraudCode": "XXXXXXXXX",**

here fraud code comes when a specific condition meet.

here is my code.

```
if(orderdetail.getFraudCancelReasonCode())
    
    {
        Reporter.log("Fraudcancel reason code doesnt Exist");
    }
```

here in above case getFraudCancelReasonCode will give the value and i can assert.

my code should be like if that fraudcode itself if its there or not and if its there i should pass 1 data
if not i should pass other data.

Please help which condition can i write here.